# How do I interact with the useState in this UserContext?

Tags: reactjs

My group is in the process of building out an app and I have built a UserContext to pass user information and to update the information to my components. I am not sure how to interact with useState here correctly.

```
import React, {createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext();
const UserUpdateContext = createContext();

export function useUser() {
    return useContext(UserContext)
}

export function useUserUpdate() {
    return useContext(UserUpdateContext)
}

export function UserProvider({ children }) {
    
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: null
      });
      

    const settingUserInfo = ( isAuth, {userInfo} ) => {
        setUser({
            isAuthenticated: isAuth,
            user: {userInfo}
        })
    }

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={ user }>
            <UserUpdateContext.Provider value={ settingUserInfo }>
            { children }
            </UserUpdateContext.Provider>
        </UserContext.Provider>

    )


}

export default UserProvider;
```

I think I would just import like this...

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { useUser, useUserUpdate }from "../utils/UserContext";
import API from '../utils/API';

export default function Component() {

    const settingUserInfo = useUserUpdate();
    const authState = useUser;

/--- code that uses state---/
```

But I am missing something about how this functions. I appreciate the time and assistance.

^_^

Comment: Have you included your provider in your app somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating your context. You can simplify it a bit to make it easier to manage. Here is an example of a userContext I use that I have refactored a bit to match your project.

```js
import React, {createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext()
const useUserContext = () => useContext(UserContext);

function UserProvider({ children }) {
    
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: null
      });
      

    const settingUserInfo = ( isAuth, {userInfo} ) => {
        setUser({
            isAuthenticated: isAuth,
            user: {userInfo}
        })
    }

  const contextValue = {
    user
    settingUserInfo,
  };

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
            { children }  
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { UserProvider, useUserContext };
```

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { useUserContext }from "../utils/UserContext";
import API from '../utils/API';

export default function Component() {
  const {user, settingUserInfo} = useUserContext()

...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yea I changed it a bit. I was overbuilding for the project and it didn't need it. Thx Richard!
I ended up going for a much simpler solution, classic model create/useContext with Provider,  but I really appreciate the time in your answer. Context was a bit difficult for me to grasp initially but I think I am getting the hang of it. Thx again!